# Excel CONCATENATE, WITH IF-formula? /:

Tags: excel, formula

I'm trying to add multiple cells together and in between them, I need an IF-formula. I'm basically making a HTML-output based on a list I have and I need to check if a column has "Active" or "Terminated" in it, and based on that choose which html-class to use. Can you help me?

What I have is:

```
=CONCATENATE(M6;M7;M8;M9;M10;M11;M12;M14;M15)
```

What I need is this, in between M12 and M13:

```
IF((Table8[Status])="Active";"<div align="left" class="active">";"<div align="left" class="terminated">
```

Both formulas work, but I cannot get them to work togheter. And as this cell is repeated below itself, and the data in column M is matched with rows in another sheet, I need this to be in the same cell.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure your if statement works properly? You need double quotes as an escape character to use double quotes in a string. I've tried this and it worked fine if I understood what your query correctly.

```
=CONCATENATE(M6;M7;M8;M9;M10;M11;M12;IF(Table8[status]="Active";"<div align=""left"" class=""active"">";"<div align=""left"" class=""terminated"">");M14;M15)
```

Comment: Thanks! That did the job!

Comment: To save a little time you can also just use `&` symbols to concatenate without the use of the concatenate function, e.g. `=M6&M7&M8&M9&M10&M11&M12&IF(Table8[status]="Active";"<div align=""left"" class=""active"">";"<div align=""left"" class=""terminated"">")&M14&M15`